# QTP - match web edit string with associated web element

Tags: qtp

I have counted number of links associated with web edit. Now, I just want to click a link which matches the web edit string.
How do I go ahead. Please suggest

Here is my code:

```
set a = Description.Create 
a("micclass").value = "WebElement" 
a("class").value = "sbqs_c" 
a("html tag").value = "DIV" 
set b = Browser("creationtime:=0").Page("title:=.*").ChildObjects(‌​a) 
MsgBox b.Count 

For i = 0 To b.count-1 Step 1 
    If b(i).GetROProperty("text")="lic" Then    
        Browser("creationtime:=0").Page("title:=.*").WebElement("c‌​lass:=sbqs_c","html tag:=DIV","index:=0").Click 
    End If 
Next
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by **associated** and **the web edit string**

Comment: it's related to auto complete, just like google search bar. There appear many suggestions when we enter a search keyword, but I want to click the link which matches the search box keyword.

Comment: here is my code:

Comment: set a=Description.Create
a("micclass").value="WebElement"
a("class").value="sbqs_c"
a("html tag").value="DIV"
set b=browser("creationtime:=0").page("title:=.*").ChildObjects(a)
msgbox b.count
'For i = 0 To b.count-1 Step 1
'print b(i).getroproperty("text")
' 
'Next
For i = 0 To b.count-1 Step 1
 If b(i).getroproperty("text")="lic" Then
  browser("creationtime:=0").page("title:=.*").webelement("class:=sbqs_c","html tag:=DIV","index:=0").Click
 End If
Next

Answer (score 1):

From your code I see that you're iterating the matching objects and then creating another object to `Click`.

One obvious problem I see is that even though you have the `i` variable you always use `"index:=0"` so you're clicking the wrong element (you should have used `"index:=" & i`).

In any case I'm not clear on why you're creating a new object in the first place, just like you did `b(i).GetROProperty` you can do `b(i).Click` (that way you don't have to mess with the index).

Comment: can you please write whole line of code here. I am new to QTP

Comment: Thanks buddy... Code is working fine.exactly the way I want it...Thank you very much...!

Comment: also can you explain me where I am creating another object and how can I am improve same code?

Comment: @user3130361, inside your `if` you're writing `Browser...` you could just use `b(i)` since you already have the object at hand (it's better since the index of an object can change if the website changes dynamically between the `ChildObjects` and the `Click`). BTW, if the answer fixed your problem please consider accepting it (by clicking the check-mark beneath the answer's score)